# PHP: How to scrape content of the website based on Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, curl, web-scraping, noscript

I'm trying to get content of this website using PHP simplehtmldom library.

http://www.immigration.govt.nz/migrant/stream/work/workingholiday/czechwhs.htm"

It is not working, so i tried using CURL:

```
function curl_get_file_contents($URL)
{
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    $contents = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);

    if ($contents) return $contents;
    else return FALSE;
}
```

But always get only respose with some JS code and content:

```
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.</noscript>
```

Is any possibility to solve this using PHP? I must use PHP in this case so i need to simulate JS based browser.

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I must use PHP in this case so i need to simulate JS based browser.

I'd recommend you two ways:

1. Leverage [v8js php plugin](http://php.net/manual/en/class.v8js.php) to deal with site's js when scraping. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070278/any-docs-about-v8js-in-php/28931743#28931743) an usage example.
2. *Simulate JS based browser* thru using [Selenium](https://webscraping.pro/using-selenium-webdriver-for-website-scraping/), iMacros or webRobots.io Chrome ext. But in this case you are off the PHP scripting.

Comment: @redrom, thanks for checking my answer, could you share of what of those  2 options has helped you? And how did you apply it? I ask you this since i do web scraping research and then post results into the scraping.pro blog. Any feedback will be appreciable!