# Downloading static web page after client-side scripts load

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, client-side

I am looking for an automatable way to download the contents of a web page after the client-side javascript app has finished loading all the divs. I know I can do this by saving the site through browser GUI, but I am looking for a solution on the command line or some other scripting method.

Things I have tried: curl, wget

Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Could you explain why curl and wget could not get the job done? wget should be able to do this with the `-p -k` options.

Comment: @KompjoeFriek neither of these tools capture the divs loaded by the client side scripts, they only return the source to run the js app

Comment: Ok, i did not understand that you wanted to include the client-side generated content.

Answer (score 0):

I've already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884428/php-how-to-scrape-content-of-the-website-based-on-javascript/28931940#28931940) to the matter of running client-side scripts on (or prior to) content load. 
If using python, you might try [PyV8](https://code.google.com/p/pyv8/) plugin.