# why is this php code not working?

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

This is the code I am using to scrape specific data from http://www.partyhousedecorations.com
however I keep getting this error (`Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\webScraping\PartyHouseDecorations.php on line 8` )and I am stuck and can't seem to be able to fix it.
This is my code:

```
<?php
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
$serv=$_GET['search'];

        $url = 'http://www.partyhousedecorations.com/category-adult-birthday-party-themes'.$serv;
        $output = file_get_html($url); 

        $arrOfStuff = $output->find('div[class=product-grid]', 0)->children();
        foreach( $arrOfStuff as $item )
        {
            echo "Party House Decorations".'<br>';
            echo $item->find('div[class=name]', 0)->find('a', 0)->innertext.'<br>'; 
            echo '<img src="http://www.partyhousedecorations.com'.$item->find('div[class=image]', 0)->find('img', 0)->src.'"><br>';
            echo str_replace('KWD', 'AED', $item->find('div[class=price]',0)->innertext.'<br>');
        }

?>
```

Comment: My bet is file_get_html is at fault. Try outputting the html and check that it's what you expect. You can avoid these problems with curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `$output->find('div[class=product-grid]', 0)` doesn't return an object with a method called `children()`. Maybe it's returning null or something that's not an object. Put it in a separate variable and look what the value of that variable is.

```
$what_is_this = $output->find('div[class=product-grid]', 0);
var_dump($what_is_this)
```

Update:

I debugged your program, and apart from the simple html dom parser seemingly expecting classes to be given as `'div.product-grid'` instead of `'div[class=x]'` it also turns out that the webpage responds by returning a product list instead of a product grid. I've included a working copy below.

```
<?php
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
$serv=$_GET['search'];

$url = 'http://www.partyhousedecorations.com/category-adult-birthday-party-themes';
$output = file_get_html($url);

$arrOfStuff = $output->find('div.product-list', 0)->children();
foreach( $arrOfStuff as $item )
{
    echo "Party House Decorations".'<br>';
    echo $item->find('div.name', 0)->find('a', 0)->innertext.'<br>';
    echo '<img src="http://www.partyhousedecorations.com'.$item->find('div.image', 0)->find('img', 0)->src.'"><br>';
    echo str_replace('KWD', 'AED', $item->find('div.price',0)->innertext.'<br>');
}
?>
```

Comment: true it does return null. however in the website, its starts with div class=product-grid and then the following components are all div, so how am i suppose to get div and all it children without having to write each one specifically on its own?

Comment: What does the $output variable actually contain? Now, I'm not great at php but the .$serv thing tagged on at the end of url looks a little funky.

Comment: its contains the URL of the website i am trying to scrape.

Comment: the $serv works perfectly, i have used the same code for other websites and it worked perfectly, the error am having is from line 8

Comment: @user3080357, seems the problem lies in content protection - in browser you have a dom element, yet cURL can't grab it. Have you checked target website being [js-protected](http://scraping.pro/javascript-protected-content-scrape/)? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884428/php-how-to-scrape-content-of-the-website-based-on-javascript/28931940#28931940) is my answer.

Comment: @user3080357 I updated my answer with a working copy of your program.