# Scrape amazon all deals php curl?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, curl

I want to scrape **amazon all deals** page

http://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/all-deals/ref=sv_gb_1

So i am using curl php

```
$request = 'http://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/all-deals/ref=sv_gb_1';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$request);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 80);
        $file_source = curl_exec($ch);
        print_r($file_source);
        exit;
```

scrapping completed but response page content div empty. contents all came from dynamic ajax requests in amazon. how can i scrap the all deal products using php and curl

My response image [**link**](http://awesomescreenshot.com/05c4ziuv03)

Update Code

```
 $request = 'http://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/all-deals/ref=sv_gb_1';
        
        $header[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        /*$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";*/
    /*  $header[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate";*/
        $header[] = 'Cookie: x-wl-uid=1vlKm5hBxhHPg37UgkrAPYZZaV0wv+T5knGezWJq0AIEWI30hJYp0XouddMIZeemj1LKAi9fDQq7aoFN+mbvlVYPTBQVLFdzs0aeTGWtiCY0Ay63L0ezPfZRKXQHC
/Wum4ywRviFW9es=; session-id-time=2082787201l; session-id=192-9168386-7231424; ubid-main=187-6710460-8617661
; session-token="+SFC4vDx/BvcD8D1Mdgeo2jtnTD0qPHF5j2nWNwbFGcRyW7/o4LBOmBHJosU5W0SgoAd6lhi0NZWg/6o5WE6o45k
+VCT5a5dgj0tltSEkBT80oWT0CDk+jCDEEhIcxnCe6aqkUn6soFiMJHIsMWujo4qyA6A70PC1xKGKdIFMUm3H0DGSdIMqITs4Mjb1
/1vY6GxnPeh5ncasxl+tUN2dHVwwJbj1ZrmyJdDxSDd8/o="; __utma=194891197.2101747155.1434117141.1434356635.1434362529
.4; __utmz=194891197.1434362529.4.4.utmccn=(referral)|utmcsr=stackoverflow.com|utmcct=/questions/11589556
/retrieving-an-amazon-stores-list-of-products-using-php|utmcmd=referral; x-main="Xi0312Ip8BrjoFoj6Zp9OLxDcU6kCvlm4DExlT5yNgHa2b3htenxvUsF2TZR3
?Fn"; s_pers=%20s_vnum%3D1866356399079%2526vn%253D2%7C1866356399079%3B%20s_invisit%3Dtrue%7C1434364356330
%3B%20s_nr%3D1434362556331-Repeat%7C1442138556331%3B; csm-hit=b-1RHERWP84F8S70KRQ903|1434453087266; preferred-geo
=national; UserPref=O9NYa0FpfOIAcRMnkQf7WL3LyhrjCsMBKgKfVxT4zK8uOTF5KjzPAwmz0DuVnfXhdkinEE1BEMgPn09eHwavl
+Hwl1BOSvjp1ewiG1iCXa0R77FsPOGbpq06MWB0MC7Wwff4gehUEAle5IfyFQqKGh1XvJ4YiMFsR2mwmyzzVJTo0WPGZzvvpCVLFmx22cRVwEi4sX8y
+IfEKu76B4p1GHPdZVo1HIwLooo8CT7lboNUi4Hhn6mhtyGCNEDLvWD8NII48Vd9EkcBjUpiSeNroRjYO9yNkj8SI3xJVI0befNipOfxAzPSnuQqeBpqm99bWArk9ZZl
+EM5QKzoPNJSF0FqVnnYavt4G6F/PHedaJVl8pU0A6N9lBjK6YZRFflyaoEYPtUW+nqK0xqO+YusAMAlhHBuW33KMdtt3i6oufQ4yTDqIgAiQ1ZTXcsb2tcu
; s_dslv=1434370132739; lc-main=en_US; aws-target-visitor-id=1434357190046-572838.22_02; aws-target-data
=%7B%22support%22%3A%221%22%7D; s_fid=7BB6DD9CE8128EC3-2A07290402DD6AF6; s_vn=1465893191447%26vn%3D1
; s_nr=1434370132733-New; s_vnum=1866370132735%26vn%3D1; skin=noskin; b2b-main=0';
        $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
        $reffer = 'http://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/all-deals/ref=sv_gb_1';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$request);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 80);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);        
        $file_source = curl_exec($ch);
        
        print_r($file_source);
```

Comment: seems to me you've encountered the dynamic js ajax requests, that are [not breakable with bare Curl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884428/php-how-to-scrape-content-of-the-website-based-on-javascript) and see also [here](http://scraping.pro/javascript-protected-content-scrape/).

Comment: @Igor Savinkin thanks for your reply. can you provide some example please

Comment: I have not yet implemented the `v8js php plugin` but my other thought is that such dynamic websites get their data thru Ajax JSON calls. You might try to find out where from the data is dynamically downloaded, (using dev. tools in browser - F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I), and then query those urls for data.

Comment: truly, the amazon queries deals thru XHR. See this [shot](http://joxi.ru/L213O50s3XEzrX); for the one mainframe (bordered in red) there are dozens of **xhr calls** for data. Seems to me they are not queryable that simple...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to contemplate an action that would violate Amazon.com's [Terms of Use](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=508088) which disallows *"any use of data mining, robots, or similar data gathering and extraction tools."*

Answer (score 2):

Based on my quick reseach you might query XHRs made by amazon to request deals.

> Such dynamic websites get their data thru Ajax JSON calls. One might try to find out where from the data is dynamically downloaded, (using dev. tools or web sniffer), and then query those urls for data.

See the [shot](http://joxi.ru/L213O50s3XEzrX). 
But if you to query them with *php Curl* you should use/imitate the http headers of that particular request headers (including cookies):
[image: request headers]

### Update

Based on your new curl request...

1. The amazon page (its js logic) makes XHR to its server for each product item. XHRs look like this: `http://www.amazon.com/xa/dealcontent/v2/GetDealMetadata?nocache=1434445645152` **not** `http://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/all-deals/ref=sv_gb_1` which is only the referer.
2. A request for product item is **POST**, not GET.
3. You probably got cookie from your browser and inserted it into the php curl header. Wrong. These cookie are of **your browser** session, not related to a session of your php server that will requests XHRs. Therefore for this use cookie jar, see the [post](http://scraping.pro/http-cookie-handler-curl/).
4. The POST's load is an object, should be formed with known structure.
   Form data:
   `{"requestMetadata":{"marketplaceID":"ATVPDKIKX0DER","sessionID":"175-4567874-0146849","clientID":"goldbox"},"widgetContext":{"pageType":"GoldBox","subPageType":"AllDeals","deviceType":"pc","refRID":"1VFVJBKEYZT3DGWSANXQ","widgetID":"1969939662","slotName":"center-6"},"page":1,"dealsPerPage":8,"itemResponseSize":"NONE","queryProfile":{"featuredOnly":false,"dealTypes":["LIGHTNING_DEAL","BEST_DEAL"],"includedCategories":["283155","599858","154606011"],"excludedExtendedFilters":{"MARKETING_ID":["restrictedcontent"]}}}`

See the developer tools picture: 
[image: see the points bordered in red]

5. As *Michael - sqlbot* mentioned, you try to do an action that violates Amazon's terms of Use. But for the *scrape technique*'s sake I still update my answer.

Comment: @NathanSrivi, how about cookies? I don't see that you use a [cookie jar](http://scraping.pro/http-cookie-handler-curl/)...

Comment: i updated all thinks now. now small update only i got

Comment: all ajax are loaded but not correctly. just run my updated code Igor Savinkin